# Why can't I start point using index lookups?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

According to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-start.html, I run the code

> START n=node:nodes(name = "A") RETURN n;

and I already create index on nodes:

> CREATE INDEX ON:nodes(name);

but it still says

> ==> MissingIndexException: Index `nodes` does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing new indexes with legacy indexes. New indexes can't be used with start, you do lookups like this:

```
MATCH (n:nodes)
WHERE n.name="A"
RETURN n
```

Comment: so, did you mean from now on, from Neo4j 2.0 or newer can't use the clause `START` anymore?

Comment: You still can with the legacy indexes, but not with new indexes that you create in Cypher like that.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your explaination.